# Retrieve mySQL Data On Radio Button Click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Through some very much appreciated help from users of this site I've been able to put together a script that upon a radio button click will populate a table with user details.

I thought that I'd be able to adapt it even further, but, quite possibly because of my lack of experience, unfortunately I've come across another problem, hence why I've added a new post.

Pulling the data from a mySQL database I'm using the code below to create a list of dates with an associated radio button.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser2.php?="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or 
die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database"); 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid,   finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC"); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)  
// table is empty  
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.';  
  else 
 {  
  echo"<table>\n"; 
  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip) = 
    mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
  { 

    echo"<tr>\n" 
    . 
     "<td><input type='radio' name='show' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' onClick='showUser(this.value)'/></td>\n" 
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n" 
    ."</tr>\n"; 
  } 
  echo'</table>'; 
} 

?> 
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then with the following code I want to populate a table with the associated 'findname' details for the radio button clicked.

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('database', $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM finds WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Find Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['findname'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I can get the first part of the script to work, i.e. the creation of the date list and radio buttons, but when I select the radio button, the table appears with the correct column heading, but I receive the following error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/getuser2.php on line 21` with line 21 being this line: `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))`.

As I said earlier the other users that answered my first post were great, but I just wondered if someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

**Updated Code**

**Form**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser2.php?="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or 
die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database"); 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.findid, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC"); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)  
// table is empty  
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.';  
  else 
 {  
  echo"<table>\n"; 
  while (list($findid, $dateoftrip) = 
    mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
  { 

    echo"<tr>\n" 
    . 
     "<td><input type='radio' name='show' dateoftrip value='{$findid}' onClick='showUser(this.value)'/></td>\n" 
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n" 
    ."</tr>\n"; 
  } 
  echo'</table>'; 
} 

?> 
<br />
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php 
//$q=$_GET["q"]; 

$con = mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password'); 
if (!$con) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db('database', $con); 

$sql="SELECT * FROM finds"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

// This is helpful for debugging
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr> 
<th>Find Name</th> 
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['findname'] . "</td>"; 

echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: How does 'WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND ... AND finds.userid = 1' in your first code script mysql_query?

Comment: @sransara thanks for that, I've now taken the `finds.userid=userdetails.userid` out of my query. Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

not

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

`mysql_fetch_array` accepts a mysql result object (which you get from the `mysql_query` function call), not a string

Comment: Hi, could perhaps elaborate on this please?

Answer (score 1):

In `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)`

`$sql` is a string, you should use `$result` instead, which is a `mysql_result` object.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for looking at this for me. I've made the change you suggested, but unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM have you checked whether your 'query result' is gving correct results - maybe try the first example in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Hi @sransara, if I've understood this correctly then the result is as follows:`Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1=1' at line 1` Kind regards

Comment: Hi @IRHM actually what i meant early was doing something like [this one](http://pastebin.com/xA8N6SjQ)

Comment: Apologies for being slow off the mark.I ran the debug.The 'id' at this line `$sql="SELECT * FROM finds WHERE id = '".$q."'";`was the problem.I've now changed this and those related to the 'fetch array'.The table now appears with the field data.However it doesn't show the relevant record for the correct radio button selected. This is a link to my page:http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/dateoftrip.php. I'm a little new to this so I've amended my original post with the new code.I just wondered if you could perhaps take a look at it please and let me know where I've gone wrong.Sincere thanks.

Comment: There are two things I could say: you may have a "where" clause in your SQL query. I cant say what it will be because it is hard to infer from the given code - maybe its something like `$sql="SELECT * FROM finds WHERE userid = '".$q."'";`. And the other thing is both the radio buttons have same values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8390/discussion-between-sransara-and-irhm)